# Ruby base 64 decoding for Java base 64 encoding

Tags: java, ruby, base64

I having a string that is encoded in java using

```
data = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encVal), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I am receiving this encoded data as an API response. I want to base64 decode this in ruby. I am using

```
Base64.strict_decode64(data)
```

for this. but this is not working. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It would help if you include a sample of such a base64-encoded string, so Ruby answerers don't have to mess around with Java just to test a solution. Also, what does this question have to do with [tag:aes]?

Comment: "KO7USRGwfmQbw3RXI6EqYJ72hnpmCzFaQbjNd1EWplus1RNKUELopYsZ9z5YyKplusQpCGstFkuwHJQ20F4R9H5u5EXu1f6DhnakteAx9hbiIEqygRdBuDM3ftrVukETHICwFD/eGo6TdyqRH5K5yjCzgjmk2TKwu5dkPS4Dm4OJF4jkB1yX/i6BMIwbXIplusrbsRYGujybxaajtTe/rXIKZbs6X5Yi2dbJuRYtTnVkg4dHZYlibplusJsoKYBTQSWNplusKXgyIQ0" .

Comment: Well, `require 'base64'; Base64.decode64(data)` should work, but I'm getting garbage out, so I can only hope you put garbage in. Strict decoder is complaining that length is not divisible by 4, and will do the same as `decode64` if you right-pad it with `=`.

Comment: `strict_decode64` will also raise `ArgumentError` for trailing linefeeds. Maybe try `Base64.strict_decode64(data.chomp)` if you want to keep using `strict_decode64` instead of the regular `decode64`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code is correct:

```
byte[] encVal = "Hello World".getBytes();
String data = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encVal), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(data); // SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=
```

The `SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=` decodes correctly using multiple tools, e.g. https://www.base64decode.org/.

You are observing garbage characters decoding your value most likely due to an error in creating `byte[]`. Possibly you have to specify the correct encoding when creating `byte[]`.